# C# Datatable filter

Tags: c#, datatable

I have 2 columns "PriceList" and "Group" in a DataTable.

```
PriceList contains, List1, List2, List3
```

Group contains, Group1, Group2, Group 3

```
var checkValues1 = new string[] { "List1", "List2" };

var checkValues2 = new string[] { "Group" };
```

This works

```
                dt.AsEnumerable().ToList().ForEach(x =>
                {
                    if (checkValues1.Contains(x["PriceList"]))
                    {
                        newDT.ImportRow(x); //Copy
                        DT.Rows.Remove(x); //Remove
                    }
                });
```

But I cant get this to work

```
                dt.AsEnumerable().ToList().ForEach(x =>
                {
                    if (checkValues2.Contains(x["Group"]))
                    {
                        newDT.ImportRow(x); //Copy
                        DT.Rows.Remove(x); //Remove
                    }
                });
```

Seems it need to be an exact match so it will only work for when group names is exactly "Group", I want it to match substrings also so "Group" would match Group1, Group2, Group 3.
Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: How much level of customization do you want? Starting with a given string, containing a given string, starting with any string on a list, containing any given string on a list...?

Comment: I just want to be able to match a substring on the column name so for group I want to be able to use "Gr" " Group" and so on and get hits from Group1, Group2, Group 3.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use starts with function.
below is example.

```
dt.AsEnumerable().ToList().ForEach(x =>
{
if (checkValues2.Any(t => t.StartsWith((x["Group"])))) 
{
newDT.ImportRow(x); //Copy
DT.Rows.Remove(x); //Remove
}
});
```

Comment: some correction in sampple code:                                                                         if (checkValues2.Any(t => t.StartsWith(x["Group"].ToString())))

Comment: I cant get this work either I dont get any hits, but if I use lets say "Group1" in checkValues2 it works but not with "Group".